# how to find a distribution of values in dataset and generate random values based on this distribution?

Tags: statistics, distribution

I have a dataset of 100 cases. Each case has a class {I,II,III,IV,V} and a value A and V, each class appears exactly 20 times in the dataset:

```
Class   A   V
5       2   3
1       3   5
3       2   3
2       3   5
3       2   3
1       2   4
1       2   4
1       4   4
2       3   3
2       3   4
```

I want to generate another 100 cases based on this set. Am i correct in assuming that I should

1. find the distribution of A and the distribution of V per class?
2. calculate the joint distribution of A & V per class
3. get random numbers based on this joint distribution

If so, any pointer to an application or library in java or python is appreciated!

Comment: "Finding" a distribution can be really challenging, especially with so few records - do you have any knowledge about the process that's generating this data? Ideas about how class might impact A and V, and how A and V might be associated? That would be a big help, I'd think.  You might also look into just resampling from your existing sample (with replacement).  More context would be helpful!

Comment: The distribution of A and V was almost normal (judging fomr the histogram though), so i generated random values from that.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to find the distribution of values in dataset I use the package rriskDistributions in R. This package, provides users a GUI that allows to choose a most appropriate distribution without any knowledge of the R syntax.

[rriskDistributions PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rriskDistributions/rriskDistributions.pdf)